# conversion error from string "0" MVC y Firebird

Tags: c#, mvc, firebird

Estoy creando una aplicación con MVC y Firebird,
tengo mi tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
Id int PK Not null
ClienteId Int
Fecha Date
Status Smallint
```

Mi class "Remision.cs" esta de la siguiente manera:

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public int ClienteId {get; set;}
public DateTime Fecha {get; set;}
public int Status {get; set;}
```

En mi ActionResult guardo de la siguiente forma:

```
databaseconexion ctx = new databaseconexion();
Remision mdl = new Remision();
mdl.ClienteId = 1;
mdl.Fecha = DateTime.Now.Date;
mdl.Status = 1;

ctx.Remision.add(mdl);
ctx.SaveChages();
```

Al ejecutar mi código obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Exception Details: FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException: conversion error from string "0"
At block line: 6, col: 1
```

Estuve investigando y en algunos foros comentan que se trata de una incompatibilidad en el formato de las fechas entre C# y Firebird, pero no se como solucionarlo :(

Answer (score 0):

Revisando mas documentación y haciendo varias pruebas, encontré que ni siquiera eran mis campos de fecha los que tenían el problema, se trata de mi campo "Ajuste" de tipo "Boolean", resulta que el tipo "bool" de C# no es compatible con "Boolean" de Firebird, recomiendan usar otro tipo de dato como "Char(1)" por ejemplo.